# Eliminate a name if a cell already has it

Tags: excel, formatting, names

In excel, I have a column list of a first name and surname together in the same cell. I have another column parallel to it with a list of the first names only.

I need a formula that checks if the name in column 1 matches that of column 2 and creates a separate column (or deletes me name from column 1) as to have a column of just surnames and one with only names.

I.e. if name is in cell *bla; cell 1 - cell 2; "error:*

Thank you

Im trying to get two separate columns with one of them containing surnames and the other first names by eliminating the redundancy of names by comparing column 2 (only first names) with column 1 (first names and surnames)

Comment: check the following link please: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)